# Confusing SVG + print behaviour in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, printing

Consider the following HTML file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      version="1.1"
      width="210mm" height="297mm">
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

One would assume that printing this document will result in a single blank page, however (in chrome at least, haven't tried other browsers) the print dialog renders it as two pages.

I tried adding the following attribute to the svg element;

`style="border: 1px solid black;"`

Just to see if the element was maybe spilling over onto the second page, and to my surprise adding a border actually caused the print dialog to only display a single page.

Can anyone explain how and why this is happening?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem with **2** SVGs. Your document prints with 1 page in Chrome 53 for me though. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Have you tried a css reset? Maybe there are still some margin added by default?